# ValueAnimator lag when set margin changed

Tags: android, animation, gpu-overdraw

I use the following class to play a animation in my app. This works well when the view tree is simple. While, it stuck when I use it in a complex fragment (i.e. the view maybe overdrawed). Is there any way to optimize the efficiency ?  I have heard about use surface view and control the redraw district of my Activity, but I need some examples. Thanks a lot.

This is my code

```
private ValueAnimator performAnim(final View target1, final int start, final int end, final int duration) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, duration);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        private IntEvaluator mEvaluator = new IntEvaluator();

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            Integer currentValue = (Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue();
            float rate = currentValue/((float)duration);
            Log.d("zcc", "currentValue" + currentValue);
            int value = mEvaluator.evaluate(rate, start, end);
            Log.d("zcc", "+" + value + "start : "+ start + " end : "+ end + " duration : " + duration);
            ((LayoutParams) target1.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = value;
            target1.requestLayout();
        }
    });

    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    return valueAnimator;
}
```

Comment: why dont you animating "translationX" / "x" property of  target1 ?

Comment: Is there any efficiency difference? I will try your advice.

Comment: actually, what i want is scale the target,

Comment: no, setting the margin, will not scale it

Comment: my layout width is matchparent , thus change margin will change its scale

Comment: scale? no, i will change its width, not scale (whatever it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requestLayout() method will measure and layout the views. Thus, the efficiency is quite low. invalid() method, which I use now, will only redraw the view I changed. Hope this may help others